# When Nero sealed Vanica, why did they wait for Vanica to use the full power of the devil?

Tags: black-clover

In *Black Clover*, when Nero sealed Vanica, why did they wait for Vanica to use the full power of the devil? What would have happened when they sealed her when she wasn't using her devil powers or when she was using a part of the devil's powers?